# Why I get the error below while fetching a feed?

Tags: javascript

`Failed to load https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

My code looks like this:

```
 fetch("https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml")
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(res => console.log(res))
```

I tried almost everything. Set headers, set modes, but nothing works. What is the problem?

Comment: it would appear that the server doesn't send a cors header. you'll have to proxy it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to do this, because the BBC website did not set the right CORS headers.

Only when the right CORS headers are set, you can make requests from other domains. Your best option is to do this via a server-side proxy, or get a job at BBC and try to add the right headers.

Comment: Then it doesn't returns nothing valuable, it returns opaque.

Comment: @GergőHorváth you're right, i was confused. Updating my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [RSS2json](https://rss2json.com/google-feed-api-alternative) instead:

```js
google.load("feeds", "1");

google.setOnLoadCallback(() => {
  const url = 'https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml';
  new google.feeds.Feed(url).load(function(result) {
    !result.error && console.log(result.feed.entries); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rss2json.com/gfapi.js"></script>
```